# true vs predicted plot

Tags: r, plot, predict

I want to plot true vs predicted per user location and Friends location. So, this is how the dataframe looks:

```
UserLocation FriendsLocation predicted true
1           DE              DE         3    3
2           NL              DE         2    2
3           DE              DE         3    2
4           FR              BE         2    2
5           IT              IT         3    2
6           IT              NL         2    2
```

dput(tr[1:10,]) gives

```
structure(list(UserLocation = structure(c(3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AT", "BE", "DE", "FR", "IT", 
"NL"), class = "factor"), FriendsLocation = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AT", "BE", "DE", 
"FR", "IT", "NL"), class = "factor"), predicted = c(3, 2, 3, 
2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), true = c(3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want a plot such that it will show the comparison between true vs predicted for every country. Could someone, please help me with this?

Comment: Is this just `ggplot(tr, aes(true, predicted, color = UserLocation))+geom_point()`?

Comment: Is this a classification or regression problem?

Comment: Its a classification problem